# How do I Make a Copy of Local Group?

Tags: windows-server-2003, users, groups

In Server 2003:

I would like to make a copy of a pre-existing local group on the server and then modify its users.

How can I make a copy of a group?  (with a new name, of course)

Alternatively, is there a way I can copy all the users from one group to another?

Comment: Scripting this would be pretty easy with adsi.  Not sure if there is an easy non-script way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/07/how-can-i-copy-the-membership-of-a-local-group-to-a-new-local-group.aspx

Another option, is to create a new group and then make the other group a member of the new group- albeit you cannot modify the members from the original group but you can add members to the new group.